# Are questions about script recommendations on topic ?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, looking-for-a-script

There is currently a tag under the name [looking-for-a-script](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/looking-for-a-script)

This tag has 53 questions. What is this tag about ? It sounds like

> "Find me a script that does X"

Is that the intended purpose of this tag ? I am just trying to understand the tag and the validity of questions under it.

For example, is this question : [javascript slider](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13954/javascript-slider) on topic ?

Comment: note that you can use [tag:tagname] syntax to simplify referring to a tag, this works anywhere in the SE network (except comments, heh)

Comment: Yay! It is prettier than before !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not *entirely* unprecedented to have a recommendation tag on a Stack Exchange site, but it is rare:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webapp-rec

The latest question currently is:

[Bulletin Board System with tagging, email notification](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14425/bulletin-board-system-with-tagging-email-notification)

Which isn't so much "looking for a script" as a general "what should I install on my webserver to do X?" shopping recommendation.

Browsing around the [looking-for-a-script](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/looking-for-a-script) tag I think these are borderline, but I don't feel strongly enough about them to effect their removal. At least the nature of the question does imply the audience is correct: if you control/operate  a webserver, then you would have the ability to install scripts and applications on that webserver of your choice.

**As long as this tag doesn't dominate the site**, and the questions and answers are generally useful to some subset of pro webmasters, they can probably be tolerated for now.

But if they are low quality or useless, of course they should be removed, as per usual. This tag is not a magic inoculation for poor quality, either!