# If I want to ask for a recommendation of a good CDN provider, can I ask here?

Tags: discussion, suitable-question

Just wondering whether it is allowed.

I want to ask for recommendation of CDN services because I guess my current CDN is not fast enough.

Can I just post it here or it's not allowed?

Comment: See their edge and pop location and read some case study that talks about throughput for large and small files. The perfect solution is test them one by one.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot ask for recommendations on this site, or most Stack Exchange sites.

We find that questions that ask for recommendations attract spam answers.

With recommendation questions, the voting system can turn into a popularity contest for which recommended service is best.   The voting is supposed to be used for well written answers.

We close such questions with the reason:

> Questions asking for recommended external websites, tools, resources, and software are off-topic as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Recommendations for software are permitted on Software Recommendations, but be sure to read their quality guidelines before posting there.

Related discussions:

- [Recommendations for specific commercial services?](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87/recommendations-for-specific-commercial-services)
- [Product recommendations and offsite resource questions, could they be made be on-topic again?](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1130/product-recommendations-and-offsite-resource-questions-could-they-be-made-be-on)
- [Are questions about script recommendations on topic ?](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/486/are-questions-about-script-recommendations-on-topic)
- [Please move questions for software recommendations to Software Recommendations.SE](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1273/please-move-questions-for-software-recommendations-to-software-recommendations-s)
- [Are Host Recommendation Questions - On Topic?](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1194/are-host-recommendation-questions-on-topic)
- [Why so much tolerance for undifferentiated CMS recommendation questions?](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/508/why-so-much-tolerance-for-undifferentiated-cms-recommendation-questions)
- [Where is it mentioned that tool recommendation questions are off-topic?](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1067/where-is-it-mentioned-that-tool-recommendation-questions-are-off-topic)